# How to use the refresh token in SugarCRM?

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, authorization, sugarcrm

I'm integrating SugarCRM into our product. I'm having a small problem with the initial authentication steps.
When I authenticate using the username and password (password grant), I get a response that's something like this.

```
{
    "access_token": "de236c59-...",
    "expires_in": 14400,
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": null,
    "refresh_token": "58113dbf-...",
    "refresh_expires_in": 14399,
    "download_token": "411000d2-..."
}
```

Now, each time I refresh the token, I get a new access token and a new refresh token. The new access token has a validity of 14400, but the new refresh token keeps the same expiry time as the previous one, and I have to use the username and password again every four hours to get new refresh and access token.

I was hoping to get the username and password from the user and not store it at all and instead just use the refresh token till it is revoked (similar to authorization code flow). Doesn't this password grant defeat the purpose of OAuth2 which was that we don't have to show our password to third party?

Is there a point in having this refresh token if it has a validity that is less than the access token here?

Comment: What API you are using? Google / Office365?

Comment: @AshishDwivedi I'm using SugarCRM Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

We can manage all tokens expiry dates in config_override.php file.

access_token lifetime should be less than refresh_token life time.

//Manipulating the access_token lifetime

```
$sugar_config['oauth2']['access_token_lifetime'] = 1800;
```

//Manipulating the refresh_token lifetime

```
$sugar_config['oauth2']['refresh_token_lifetime'] = 3600;
```

If you want to explicit expire the session of a user after fixed period of time, then you can use this:

```
$sugar_config['oauth2']['max_session_lifetime'] = 1209600;
```